# Can't access running service using Docker Stack and Official Wordpress Docker image

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to deploy a stack with a compose file using the [official Wordpress Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/).

I have stripped down my down my compose file (stack.yml) to this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_password

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_password

secrets:
  db_password:
    file: db_password.txt
```

With the exception of secrets, this almost exactly what is given in the documentation.

I then run `$ docker stack deploy -c stack.yml wordpress`.

Running `$ docker stack services wordpress` confirms that both services are replicated and running.

```
NAME                  MODE                REPLICAS
wordpress_wordpress   replicated          1/1
wordpress_mysql       replicated          1/1
```

However, when I try to access from `http://localhost:8080` in Chrome, I get the following message:

```
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

The image documentation also mentions accessing from `http://swarm-ip:8080`.

I tried running `docker node inspect self --format '{{ .Status.Addr  }}'` which returned the ip `192.168.65.2`, however visiting `192.168.65.2:8080` in Chrome returns `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

I'm running Docker 17.06.0-ce-mac19 on Mac Sierra 10.12.6.

Is this just a configuration error on my particular machine? Or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Use `docker service logs wordpress_wordpress` and see what you see in logs

Comment: @TarunLalwani the only thing that seems odd is this message:
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: what is the content of your `db_password.txt`? I check the above on my system with environment variables instead of secret using `docker stack` and it all works for me

Comment: @TarunLalwani I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. It turns out that it was the secret was I was using. I had typed some random words and characters in the secret, which included a `!` character. This was causing mysql to fail. Once I removed the `!` characters everything is up and running perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the contents of `db_password.txt`. I have checked the above on my system with environment variables instead of secrets, using `docker stack` and it all works for me